# Loop in Rules not picking up VBO data

Tags: 7, rules, views

I have a Views of users (friends of the current user) and I have added a VBO field to it. The objective is that when an event is created by the current user, their friends receive an email about it.

I created a Rule, and using VBO (release 7.x-3.3), I try to send an email to people. Right now, the loop is not picking up any data, even if the View is working properly. Am I missing something?

PS: The rule first shows a message to confirm that it has been triggered, and I am testing the loop with a status message.

```
{ "rules_test_loop_triggeredvbo" : {
"LABEL" : "test_loop_triggeredVBO",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "views_bulk_operations" ],
"ON" : { "node_insert--event" : { "bundle" : "event" } },
"DO" : [
  { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Rule when event is created is TRIGGERED" } },
  { "views_bulk_operations_action_load_list" : {
      "USING" : {
        "view" : "clone_of_profile_friends|page",
        "args" : "[site:current-user]"
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_list" : { "entity_list" : "A list of entities" } }
    }
  },
  { "LOOP" : {
      "USING" : { "list" : [ "entity-list" ] },
      "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
      "DO" : [
        { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "User has friend:  [list-item:name]" } }
      ]
    }
  }
]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using 7.x-3.3...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these VBO issues:

- [views_bulk_operations_action_load_list not working](https://www.drupal.org/node/2853029).
- [Load a list of entity from a VBO View doesn't work (AJAX error)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1871702).

Since you're using the 7.x-3.3 release of VBO, I recommend you retry your scenario with at least the [7.x-3.4 release](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/releases/7.x-3.4). However, as per [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1871702#comment-12165651) you might only get it to work using the latest DEV version of VBO.